# how to repeat an alarm android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

How to repeat an alarm manager to run my activity once in 30 minutes?
How to simply run this main activity once in 30 minutes can anybody explain me pls

code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

Comment: where is your alarm code..are you looking for tutorial about alarm.. if yes look at this .http://stackoverflow.com/a/8801990/964741

Comment: hey @pureindian is it not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void setLocationSendingAlarm() {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleMapService.class);
    intent.putExtra("locationSendingAlarm", true);
    PendingIntent   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 987654321, intent,0);
    try {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    int timeForAlarm=60000;


    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+50000, timeForAlarm, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: timeForAlarm this is repeating time

Comment: put your time in timeForAlarm in milliseconds

Comment: if u don't understand see this link http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/schedule-repeating-alarm.html

Answer (score 0):

see [AlarmManager.setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method. you can check this [example](https://github.com/rakeshcusat/Code4Reference/tree/master/AndroidProjects/AlarmManagerExample)